# How to make cross origin get request via angularjs http using food2fork api

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, jsonp

I'm simply trying to make a get request using food2fork's search api in an angular app. Right now I've got no backend to the app, so everything is running client side, and I'm running the following (with the APIKEY replaced, of course):

```
$http.jsonp('http://food2fork.com/api/search?q=turkey&key=APIKEY&callback=jsonp_callback')
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

However, I'm `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in the console. I assume this is because it's expecting a jsonp function rather than json.

If I run it as a jquery getJSON, as seen here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?q=turkey&key=APIKEY";
$.getJSON(url,function(data) {
})
```

});

I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access.` - which may be because I'm running locally, but that hasn't been a problem in the past.

I just want to get the json that I get if I run the same request as a url in a browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

You are facing [Cross Domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem and what you should do is enabling `CORS` from your server side (the service running from localhost:8080)

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm doing everything client side. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm saying configure your SERVER side, not client.